# 'add-apt-repository' command gives Traceback error

Tags: apt, repository, ppa

I wanted to install nvidia graphics drivers. My python version is 3.11.2

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

This command gives the following erros:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 362, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 345, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 86, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
       ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 126, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 113, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'
```

I tried reinstalling 'software-properties-common' with `$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` but no luck.

(I clean installed Ubuntu 23.04)

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue and was able to solve installing the python3-launchpadlib:

`apt install python3-launchpadlib`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).